# How to send multiple variables to PHP using an AngularJS Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I am learning angularJS and I want to know how can I send multiple data variables through Angular AJAX like I could do with Jquery?

This is how I did it with Jquery:

```
$.post("eventCreate.php",
                        {
                            daySelect: daySelect,
                            startTime: startTime,
                            endTime: endTime,
                            eventName: eventName,
                            loginName: "<?php echo $user; ?>",
                            sliderName: sliderName
                        },
                        function(result)
                        {
                          ;
                        });
```

So how do I do this with Angularjs? Is it possible?

Comment: In angularjs you use $http directive to send the $get and $post request and there are some what similar to jQuery

Comment: http://techfunda.com/howto/565/http-post-server-request

Answer (score 1):

You can use $http and $resource service of angular.I mostly use $http.You can send multiple variable in angular js ajax call in data or params atttibute of $http as given below

```
$http({
    url: user.details_path, 
    method: "GET",
    params: {user_id: user.id,user_name:user.name}
 });

 $http({
        url: user.details_path, 
        method: "GET",
        data: userObject
     });
```

Answer (score -2):

In AngularJs we create `Controllers` and do our things in it. AngularJs support `POST` and `GET` method as well.
In this code i am giving you a demo for `POST` method. Change `variable name` according to you and you can increase and decrease them as well.

Use `$_POST` for server side to get the value of these.

```
$scope.YourControllerName = function () {
    var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'YourURL',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            data: {
                userId: userId,
                userName: userName, // Or anything you want to send
                action: "addUser"  //Suppose you are adding a user
               },
            }

            $http(req).then(function(response){
                //This will called on success do something with this response
            }, function(response){
                //This will called on failure do something with this response
            });
        };
```